# What comment-spam filtering service works?

Tags: spam

From an answer I gave to another question:

> There are comment filtering services out there that can analyse comments in a manner similar to mail spam filters (all links to the client API page, organised from simplest API to most complex):
>
> 1. Steve Kemp (again) has [an xml-rpc-based comment filter](http://blogspam.net/api/): it's how Debian filters comments, and the code is free software, meaning you can run your own comment filtering server if you like;
> 2. There's [Akismet](http://akismet.com/development/api/), which is from the WordPress universe;
> 3. There's [Mollom](http://mollom.com/api), which has an impressive list of users.  It's closed source; it might say "not sure" about comments, intended to suggest offering a captcha to check the user.

For myself, I'm happy with offline by-hand filtering, but I suggested Kemp's service to someone who had an underwhelming experience with Mollom, and I'd like to pass on more reports from anyone who has tried these or other services.

Comment: I'm in the process of overhauling the blogspam testing facility so any feedback is most welcome and extra-timely.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the main question, but I've found Web-Of-Trust very good for filtering URLs submitted in comments. WOT returns a reputation score for different factors like trustworthy-ness and child-safety. They have a fairly simple JSON/REST API

Answer (score 1):

There is an API at [www.atlbl.com](http://www.atlbl.com) that you can query for IP address, hostname, domain, full URL, and even email address, to help combat comment spam etc.

Comment: Good to know.  There isn't anything I can find that would help me evaluate the service: How complex is the interface? How good is their algorithm in terms of getting an acceptable false +ve/-ve rate?

Comment: You can get an account for free, API is just simply REST-XML or you can use the DNSBL's. Data is all reputation based and scored, so you can build in your own trigger/threshold points.

Comment: @cwopen: The site says "invitation only"...  There are three things specifically I am interested in, in order: (1. most important) low incidence of false negatives, (2) how much work is it to integrate the API into existing weblog software, particularly hand-crafted software, and get it to work the way we want, and (3. least) low false positive rate.

Comment: Where did you see "invitation only" ? It's been out of beta for quite some quite now. You should just need to drop them an email to get an account set-up.
False negative's should be low if at all as it's a dynamic lookup, rather than an hourly download or something.
The API is very simple, just a HTML call, so just a couple of lines of code in php,perl,whatever.
False positive's should be very low as the delisting is automatic and you can setup your own threshold's anyway.